# Apache server taking down network

Tags: windows, networking, php, web-server, xampp

Sorry everyone.  I'm an amateur at this so my setup probably isn't what you'd call ideal, but I should be able to give enough info to move things along.

At work, we are on a Comcast connection and normally run all our dns through an internal server which forwards to an outside dns server if it doesn't have an answer.  This internal server also runs an install of XAMPP which is Apache & PHP for windows.  The dns server is Bind9.

Up to the middle of this week, everything was working flawlessly.  Network computers had access to outside internet as well as our internally hosted domains.  The server is connected to our router via an ethernet cable.

Sometime earlier this week, we needed to hook up another computer to our router through ethernet so plugged in the server and new computer through an ethernet switch.  For a short period of time the server appeared to work on the switch, but quickly we had issues so we removed the switch.  Everything should have been the same as it was before.

However, now, if we run Apache on the server, it takes up 80% of cpu and we no longer have access to the internet or internal sites.  Turning Apache off gives us internet back but means we cannot continue to develop websites internally.

So, my question is, what happened to Apache?  And, how can one computer on a network, with a rogue apache process keep everyone off the internet?

Comment: Well, I went ahead and reinstalled XAMPP.  It took about 3 hours of work but things seem to be running smoothly now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something on the server has gone haywire and it may have nothing to do with the router or traffic. Perhaps the server doesn't have the resources available to perform it's DNS responsibilities adequately when apache is running. Try changing your DNS information to googles publicly available DNS servers temporarily and see if you can then access the internet with apache running. If you can then it's likely a DNS issue. If you still can't then try running wireshark for windows on the server and look for any weird inbound outbound traffic coming from the server.

Google DNS: 8.8.4.4   8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0):

Well, I went ahead and reinstalled XAMPP. It took about 3 hours of work but things seem to be running smoothly now